# I want to go back to my fragment screen after clicking "textview" on my "floatingservice" class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-windowmanager

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service  {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
mFloatingView = 
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.homescree_layout_one, 

null);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        layout_parms,

        // WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 100;
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
 textviewApply = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.textviewApply);
textviewApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your theme applied          successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
```

Here, `textviewApply` is used for setting the floating window.
I want to go back to my fragment screen after clicking textview on the `floatingservice`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case that is good to use Broadcast Receiver:

Here a good example to build a custom broadcast receiver:

https://www.journaldev.com/10356/android-broadcastreceiver-example-tutorial

And cast if you want to learn more about the subject:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: why broadcast receiver ? i just want to go back to my fragment page buddy .

Comment: You can run the receiver listener on the fragment and show it from there (if it is open)
Or put the link on the activity and open away a new fragment.
If that is not your intention, you can explain the question again